# UI Div alignments in CSS Bootstrap and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in my UI . One div contains a label . 
And the other one contains a file selector . I want them to be side by side.

But now they are stacked vertically . [image]

How can I align them horizontally with a little space between them ?

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Upload File</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-select">
            <input type="file" name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br/>
    <div style="height:3px; background-color:#cccccc; width:100%; margin-top:5px;"></div>
    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100px;" value="Upload" />

    </div>
```

Comment: Please post a Jsfiddle along with CSS

Comment: Your two main containers need to be `display: inline-block`, also the width needs to be fixed

Comment: If it is bootstrap form use class form inline ``<form class="form-inline" role="form">``

Answer (score 2):

I think this should solve your problem

```css
.form-label,.form-input{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="form-label">
            <label>Upload File</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-select form-input">
            <input type="file" name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, just by adding display:inline-block and float left .. like Bootstrap
**Or** if you are already using bootstrap just use their grid classes like "col-xs-6" for both divs
getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```css
.label-container{display:inline-block;float:left;margin-right:25px;}
.input-container{display:inline-block;float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <div class="label-container">
            <label>Upload File</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="file" name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br/>
    <div style="height:3px; background-color:#cccccc; width:100%; margin-top:5px;"></div>
    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100px;" value="Upload" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap you can wrap them in a `form` element of class `form-inline`

If you're not using Bootstrap you can use `float: left` and some margin to create the space between them like this:

```css
.inline{
    float: left;
}

.ui-select{
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
    <label>Upload File</label>
</div>
<div class="inline ui-select">
    <input type="file" name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code this one.

```
 <div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label>Upload File</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-select" style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">
        <input type="file" name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<br/>
<div style="height:3px; background-color:#cccccc; width:100%; margin-top:5px;"></div>
<div style="padding-top:10px;">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100px;" value="Upload" />

</div>
```